# Who writes the Dragon Ball Heroes anime?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

So, it's known Akira Toriyama doesnt write the Dragon Ball Heroes directly or indirectly (such as he did with Dragon Ball Super), so, if it isnt Akira Toriyama who makes it, who is or are the persons behind it? is it someone who worked in Dragon Ball movies or animes (Dragon Ball GT or whatever) before, or is/are they completely new writers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Heroes#Anime), the writer for episodes 1-5 of Dragon Ball Heroes is **Atsuhiro Tomioka**. The writer for episode 6 is apparently still TBA. However, I can't find what source they're citing for this information.

He has previously been involved with Dragon Ball Super, having written the script for 22 episodes, according to [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=1623).

Answer (score 0):

Only info I could dig up is that [Tadayoshi Yamamuro](https://myanimelist.net/people/35739/Tadayoshi_Yamamuro) is listed as "Director" on MyAnimeList. It seems he's had a large contributing part to Heroes as he's also listed as "Character Design", "Storyboard", and "Chief Animation Director" for the series as well.

Answer (score -1):

the storyline is written by the creators of the arcade game but oda has input it's mainly written by the fans though cause its main purpose is fan service if an idea is voiced loud enough it will likely go into the anime

Comment: Could you provide more concrete evidence like e.g. sources/references for this answer? Especially the fan service part, like where/how did they collect the idea from the fans? As of now, this looks more like a speculation/theory, not a fact.